# How to make parallel a web api calls in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a project where I will have to make more than 100k web api calls. This is required for initializing an application with the data from some other system. This is one time activity.The api does not provide any thing like batch processing, neither do that have async methods. If I just call them in a normal way it is taking more than a day to complete the whole process process. Can somebody suggest a good way to accomplish in an efficient way ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The normal way, such as ?

Comment: Do you control the API? If not, and you need to make 100k calls into it, then it's certainly worth contacting the API owner to see if they can make your life easier... You're definitely not using it in a way that they anticipated.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I don't have control on API. They don't seem to have any issue serving parallel requests. I am trying to make use of c# features to fire the API requests in parallel so that a request don't have to wait for the other request to complete.

Comment: For a particular request to be made, does it rely on information gained from a previous request, or (in an ideal world) could you fire off 100k requests simultaneously?

Comment: Each request is independant. How can I fire off all the requests simultaneously ? The methods are not async methods.

Comment: You'd need to share some code to show us what you're doing now.

Answer (score 0):

You could spawn 100K threads that would be if possible executed asynchronously (all the data is independent), if the API calls need to be synchronous (each call depends on data returned by the previous one), you might change the priority of the threads to be executed in bigger priority in order to have the OS give your program top priority.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: This is what I have been thinking  of doing, but I was not so sure how many threads I can launch with out getting stuck on resources and in the end not able to complete the process.  I may have to do some more reading on threading topic. Thanks for the response.

Comment: It depends ... looks like you know nothing about OS or kernels or pthreads ... databases and os inside big data clusters are used to that number of threads and more